# Matlab: finding coefficients of ODE system

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, ode

I have all the data and an ODE system of three equations which has 9 unknown coefficients (a1, a2,..., a9).

```
dS/dt = a1*S+a2*D+a3*F
dD/dt = a4*S+a5*D+a6*F
dF/dt = a7*S+a8*D+a9*F

t = [1 2 3 4 5]
S = [17710 18445 20298 22369 24221]
D = [1357.33 1431.92 1448.94 1388.33 1468.95]
F = [104188 104792 112097 123492 140051]
```

How to find these coefficients (a1,..., a9) of an ODE using Matlab?

Comment: you problalby mean dS/dt,...?

Comment: This is a simple linear system, so you can solve it analytically. You may then fit the solution to the data, although you probably need more observations to constrain your parameters!

Comment: Ander, exactly. I fixed it. How to solve in Matlab, any examples?

Comment: Better fits http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidZwicker: you're saying 15 equations aren't enough to solve for 9 unknowns? :)

Comment: Well, the system is overdetermined, if you assume that the data is exact. I implicitly assumed that the provided data stems from measurements and a fit is required to get the coefficients. In that case, 15 points are usually not enough to determine the coefficients.

Comment: @DavidZwicker: Overdetermined systems usually allow for a least-squares solution...I think that's what intended here

Answer (score 1):

You have a linear, coupled system of ordinary differential equations,

```
y' = Ay    with    y = [S(t);  D(t);  F(t)]
```

and you're trying to solve the *inverse* problem,

```
A = unknown
```

Interesting!

### First line of attack

For given `A`, it is possible to solve such systems analytically (read [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) for example).

The general solution for 3x3 design matrices `A` take the form

```
[S(t) D(t) T(t)].' = c1*V1*exp(r1*t) + c2*V2*exp(r2*t) + c3*V3*exp(r3*t)
```

with `V` and `r` the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of `A`, respectively, and `c` scalars that are usually determined by the problem's initial values.

Therefore, there would seem to be two steps to solve this problem:

1. Find vectors `c*V` and scalars `r` that best-fit your data
2. reconstruct `A` from the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

However, going down this road is treaturous. You'd have to solve the non-linear least-squares problem for the sum-of-exponentials equation you have (using `lsqcurvefit`, for example). That would give you vectors `c*V` and scalars `r`. You'd then have to unravel the constants `c` somehow, and reconstruct the matrix `A` with `V` and `r`.

So, you'd have to solve for `c` (3 values), `V` (9 values), and `r` (3 values) to build the 3x3 matrix `A` (9 values) -- that seems too complicated to me.

### Simpler method

There is a simpler way; use brute-force:

```
function test

    % find  
    [A, fval] = fminsearch(@objFcn, 10*randn(3))

end

function objVal = objFcn(A)

    % time span to be integrated over
    tspan = [1 2 3 4 5];

    % your desired data
    S = [17710    18445    20298    22369    24221   ];
    D = [1357.33  1431.92  1448.94  1388.33  1468.95 ];
    F = [104188   104792   112097   123492   140051  ];

    y_desired = [S; D; F].';

    % solve the ODE
    y0 =  y_desired(1,:);
    [~,y_real] = ode45(@(~,y) A*y, tspan, y0);

    % objective function value: sum of squared quotients
    objVal = sum((1 - y_real(:)./y_desired(:)).^2);

end
```

So far so good.

However, I tried both the complicated way and the brute-force approach above, but I found it very difficult to get the squared error anywhere near satisfyingly small.

The best solution I could find, after numerous attempts:

```
A =
    1.216731997197118e+000    2.298119167536851e-001   -2.050312097914556e-001
   -1.357306715497143e-001   -1.395572220988427e-001    2.607184719979916e-002
    5.837808840775175e+000   -2.885686207763313e+001   -6.048741083713445e-001

fval =
    3.868360951628554e-004
```

Which isn't bad at all :) But I would've liked a solution that was less difficult to find...

Comment: As a simple note, this is a plain example of the butterfly effect, whereas if I simply plug your A matrix into the solution, I get a very incorrect result at t=5. More sig figs are needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RodyOldenhuis When I run this function first time it calculates the results in a seconds, but when I try to run second time, it is running eternally and doesn't stop. I am using Matlab 7.11.0 Does it happen for you? How do you chose the best solution after numerous attempts? With lowest difference between given points?

Answer (score 1):

I can't spend too much time on this, but basically you need to use math to reduce the equation to something more meaningful:

your equation is of the order

**dx/dt = A*x**

ergo the solution is

**x(t-t0) = exp(A*(t-t0)) * x(t0)**

Thus

**exp(A*(t-t0)) = x(t-t0) * Pseudo(x(t0))**

Pseudo is the Moore-Penrose Pseudo-Inverse.

EDIT: Had a second look at my solution, and I didn't calculate the pseudo-inverse properly.

Basically,  **Pseudo(x(t0)) = x(t0)'*inv(x(t0)*x(t0)')**, as x(t0) * Pseudo(x(t0)) equals the identity matrix

Now what you need to do is assume each time step (1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4) is an experiment (therefore t-t0=1), so the solution would be to:

1- Build your pseudo inverse:

```
xt = [S;D;F];
xt0 = xt(:,1:4);

xInv = xt0'*inv(xt0*xt0');
```

2- Get exponential result

```
xt1 = xt(:,2:5);
expA =  xt1 * xInv;
```

3- Get the logarithm of the matrix:

```
A = logm(expA);
```

And since t-t0= 1, A is our solution.

And a simple proof to check

```
[t, y] = ode45(@(t,x) A*x,[1 5], xt(1:3,1));
plot (t,y,1:5, xt,'x')
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't calculate the pseudo-inverse properly... Corrected

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Basically you're applying the same weight to all three variables despite one being several orders of magnitude greater then the others. If you looked at relative values (sum((1-y(:)./xt(:)).^2), my solution is 4.4922e-04 vs 0.0143. In other words, while you punish F from deviating, you're a lot more lenient on D.

Comment: I'm still a bit fuzzy on the details of your method...How would you have solved the problem when the increment in `t` was non-uniform?

Comment: Also, when I take your solution as an initial estimate and run it through an optimizer, I can pretty easily reduce the sum of relative squared errors down to `3.86846e-004` (same for absolute errors). This means your solution is not optimal in a least-squares sense...Perhaps we can take the discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392594/how-to-solve-for-the-matrix-in-a-set-of-equations-involving-the-matrix-exponenti).

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis This is a LS solution to the exponential of A. That's what Moore-Penrose provides (cf. wikipedia). While I'm not using all the data points I could to further refine the solution, the approximation error is judged to be small and relatively trivial by engineering standards and would be considered sufficient. Parameter estimation is a very ugly subject, and one should take any solution that does the job.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis As for non-uniform t value: most engineering applications sample t at regular intervals. Will my solution work for variable t? Not in the present form, but there are algorithms that can handle that. OP had a simple problem, ergo I gave him a simple solution.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have a few questions:
1) "assume each time step (1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4)" - where do you assume that each time step in your code?
2) "xt0 = xt(:,1:4);" - why do take just 4 data points from the data and leave the fifths?

Comment: @shummis xt0's columns has time step 1, 2, 3 and 4 and xt1 has time step 2, 3, 4 and 5

Comment: Ok, but why don't you do with xt0 = xt(:,1:5) ?

Comment: @shummis The problem involves trying to project data points from one state to another. t=1 projects to t=2, t=2 projects to t =3... t = 5 therefore would project onto t = 6, which you don't provide (and I can't create data). I can only use t=5 as an end point. Similarly, I can only use t = 1 as a starting point since I don't have t =0.

Comment: @Rasman, how to deal with that time steps if I have more data?
t = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]
S = [17110 18045 19898 22069 23621 24414 24294 24433 24302 23107 22074 21162]
D = [1157.33 1231.92 1248.94 1188.33 1268.95 1215.5 1298.84 1302.99 1235.16 1210.36 1535.1 1541.52]
F = [104181 104790 112092 123490 140048 149941 172326 194574 227427 219278 215672 242864]
How to solve this? Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Sorry @Rasman if my questions look stupid for you, but I need your help very much. Can you help me with previous question?

Comment: @shummis Use my code above and when you see either `4` or `5` replace it as would be necessary

Comment: @Rasman I did that and got parables which show trends well but don't fit with the data very precisely.

Comment: @shummis You're doing parameter estimation on what appears to be an unstable system. It is very hard to get these things to behave especially in these circumstances. Ask yourself if the model is correct and if you don't like the answer crack open a textbook and find a better solution or try the cross validated stack exchange. Also, data noise/error is expected in these circumstances... it's like imagining the shape of the ice from a water puddle.

Comment: http://imajna.oxfordjournals.org/content/25/2/264.abstract and especially http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/366/1865/519.abstract